# i18n node.js setLocale not working! getLocale ALWAYS returns the default locale

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization

I dont know if im using i18n library wrong but I am pretty sure im doing it right.

I have been trying to change the locale. Here is my current code. As you can see I call setLocale on the glocal i81n variable but it still prints out en

I have tried to do res.setLocale(req.args.lang); in my controller BUT IT STILL PRINTS OUT the default language of en.

I honestly don't know if this library is just broken or I'm doing this completely wrong. Please help!

```js
/**
 * Main Express Application: set up express app
 */

'use strict';

// require third-party node modules
const express = require('express');
const sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect');
const compression = require('compression');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors'); // handle cors
const i18n = require('i18n'); // set up language

// env variables
const { NODE_ENV, COOKIE, REDIS_URL, REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT } = process.env;

// server
function server() {
  // require custom
  const models = require('./models'); // establish and grab db connection
  const cfgPassport = require('./services/passport'); // configuration for passport

  // require custom middleware
  const args = require('./middleware/args');
  const error = require('./middleware/error');
  const exit = require('./middleware/exit');
  const { attachJWTAuth } = require('./middleware/auth');

  // set up express app
  const app = express();
  const newServer = http.createServer(app);
  const io = require('socket.io')(newServer); // socket.io


  // set up redis with socket
  const redis = require('socket.io-redis');
  const socket = require('./services/socket'); // require socket service to initiate socket.io
  io.adapter(redis(REDIS_URL));

  // enable ssl redirect in production
  app.use(sslRedirect());

  // only log requests in development
  NODE_ENV === 'development' ? app.use(require('morgan')('dev')) : null;

  // add middleware and they must be in order
  app.use(compression()); // GZIP all assets
  app.use(cors()); // handle cors
  app.use(helmet()); // protect against vulnerabilities
  // app.use(rawBody); // adds rawBody to req object

  // set up language
  i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'ko'], // set the languages here
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    queryParameter: 'lang', // query parameter to switch locale (ie. /home?lang=ch) - defaults to NULL
    cookie: COOKIE,
    directory: __dirname + '/locales'
  });

  // you will need to use cookieParser to expose cookies to req.cookies
  app.use(cookieParser());

  // i18n init parses req for language headers, cookies, etc.
  // NOTE: If user is logged in, locale is set in verifyJWTAuth method
  app.use(i18n.init);
  i18n.setLocale('ko');
  console.log(i18n.getLocale());

  // save raw body
  function rawBodySaver(req, res, buf, encoding) {
    if (buf && buf.length) req.rawBody = buf.toString(encoding || 'utf8');
  }

  // body parser
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '32mb', verify: rawBodySaver })); // raw application/json
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '32mb', verify: rawBodySaver, extended: false })); // application/x-www-form-urlencoded

  // NOTE: take this out because it interferes with multer
  // app.use(bodyParser.raw({ limit: '32mb', verify: rawBodySaver, type: () => true }));

  // only secure in production
  if (NODE_ENV === 'production') app.set('trust proxy', 1); // get ip address using req.ip

  // passport config, must be in this order!
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  cfgPassport(passport); // set up passport

  // custom middleware
  app.use(args.attach); // set req.args
  app.use(attachJWTAuth(passport));
  app.use(exit.middleware); // stops here if server is in the middle of shutting down

  // host public files
  // app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

  // set up routes
  const router = require('./routes')(passport); // grab routes
  app.use('/', router); // place routes here

  // error middleware MUST GO LAST
  app.use(error);

  // io connection, call socket.connect
  io.on('connection', socket.connect);

  return newServer; // return newServer
}

module.exports = server(); // return server app for testing
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out by accident.

This really should be in the documentation but I will post it here so that other poor souls who ran into this issue can try this out.

The reason why nothing was working WAS BECAUSE my .json file had a trailing comma. Therefore it wasn't a valid .json file.

It took me two days to accidentally discover this. i18n SHOULD HAVE THROW AN ERROR in the console if the .json files are invalid!!!

Anyways, I removed the trailing comma and everything just worked.

Comment: @hackbryd: Oh man! Thanks so much, I lost a bunch of time on the same stupid problem. This should ABSOLUTELY be somewhere in the docs.